# "WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist."

Tags: virtualbox

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-amd64.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

This is the error I get when I run `virtualbox` in command line... Is there anything I can do?

I have tried to update the apt-get and I have tried to run the virtual box... But it does not work properly

**Update**
It is giving this off now.

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-amd64.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

(process:4695): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

(process:4695): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

(process:4695): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Qt WARNING: QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
Qt WARNING: Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported

(process:4695): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Comment: Why update `apt-get` when the error explicitly tells you to install `virtualbox-dkms` and the linux headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear.

You have to install 2 packages :

```
# apt-get update; apt-get install virtualbox-dkms linux-headers-amd64
```

Comment: I did this and it did not install anything... It also did not update anything

Comment: I uninstalled the file and re-installed it.

Comment: @AmateurProgramer Post the output of `dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms` (edit your question). Also post the output of `lsmod |grep vbox`.